React native swift module does not have RCTResponseBlock
im trying to develop live activity module in my app. When the activity is created, i need to return activityToken from native code to js code. I have read that getting activityToken from live activity is async function so i need RCTResponseBlock in my native function.
The problem is, RCTResponseBlocks dont exist in my swift code and idk why.
here are my files:

My file tree 
widget bridge.m
Bridging-Header.h
WidgetModule.swift
I need to access RCTResponseBlock in my swift code?
Im on a RN 0.73.3 version
